# Enabling TSLint in VS Code

Tags: typescript, tslint

I have a situation where tslint is working on SOME VS Code projects while not working on other projects. The projects where it's working are from [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) with TypeScript modifications.
But when I create a new TypeScript (non-React) project and just copy the tslint.json from the React app, tslint does not work (no errors/warnings - nothing).

Here's the `tslint.json` I'm using for both apps:

```
{
  "extends": ["tslint:recommended", "tslint-react", "tslint-config-prettier"],
  "linterOptions": {
    "exclude": [
      "config/**/*.js",
      "node_modules/**/*.ts"
    ]
  },
  "rules": {
    "ordered-imports": false
  }
}
```

Here's the way I create a new TypeScript React project with a working tslint:

```
create-react-app <app-name> --scripts-version=react-scripts-ts
```

I also checked my VS Code Settings and the following is set for both projects:

```
"tslint.enable": true,
```

`tsconfig.json` for the "tslint working" project (generated by create-react-app):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "build/dist",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build",
    "scripts",
    "acceptance-tests",
    "webpack",
    "jest",
    "src/setupTests.ts"
  ]
}
```

`tsconfig.json` for the "tslint not working" project (generated by me):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "es5",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017','ES2018' or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    // "lib": [],                             /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    // "allowJs": true,                       /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    // "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
    // "jsx": "preserve",                     /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
    // "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                /* Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    // "outFile": "./",                       /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
    // "outDir": "./",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    // "rootDir": "./",                       /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    // "composite": true,                     /* Enable project compilation */
    // "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    // "noEmit": true,                        /* Do not emit outputs. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                 /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,            /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
    // "isolatedModules": true,               /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    // "noImplicitAny": true,                 /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,           /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,  /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */

    /* Additional Checks */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    "moduleResolution": "node",            /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    // "baseUrl": "./",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    // "paths": {},                           /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    // "types": [],                           /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
    // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,  /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true                   /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */

    /* Source Map Options */
    // "sourceRoot": "./",                    /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    // "mapRoot": "./",                       /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

    /* Experimental Options */
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,        /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */
  },
  "include": [
        "src/**/*",
        "test/**/*",
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/38739699/356218

The VSCode TSLint extension does not seem to be good at surfacing config errors.  Try running `tslint -c tslint.json 'src/**/*.ts'` from commandline and make sure it doesn't give errors regarding config issues.

(Edited answer based on conversation in comments)

Comment: Yes, both have tsconfig.json and tslint.json. I should've mentioned the tsconfig.json for both projects in my question.

Comment: And both have a similar structure?  All the ts files being in `/src/` subfolders?  I'd also suggest trying to run tslint via commandline to see if that gives more helpful errors

Comment: Can you successfully tslint from commandline?: `tslint -c tslint.json 'src/**/*.ts'`  Also compare the `package.json`, specifically the `scripts` sections, perhaps VSCode is looking for `build`, which with the bootstrapper defaults to `react-scripts-ts start`.  Perhaps try making a copy of the bootstrapper version, and use `npm run eject`, and see if it still works, and see what the `build` script is after that.

Comment: Yes, that helped - tslint on command line complains about the 2 extensions I included: Invalid "extends" configuration value - could not require "tslint-config-prettier" and Invalid "extends" configuration value - could not require "tslint-react". When I remove "tslint-config-prettier" and "tslint-react" from "extends" it works. So it only finds "tslint:recommended". Is there a way to include "tslint-config-prettier" for a non React project?

Comment: So sounds like within the same realm as this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38739699/356218  The extension isn't good at surfacing config errors :/

Comment: Yup, saw that question but no one suggested running tslint on command line  like you did - you should add your answer there too. TS Lint in VS Code just stays silent and doesn't say anything is wrong - annoying...

Answer (score 21):

This fixed it for me.
(cmd + shift + p)
to find 'TSLint: Manage workspace library execution'
then
'Enable workspace library execution'

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. This solved my issue. I was not getting TS problems highlighted or auto-fixed on save. Though ather than "Enable workspace library execution",  I chose "Always enable workspace library execution" which turned on this feature for all of my projects. I did have to have a TS file open and in focus to surface the TSLint options, though.

Comment: Ya,  a matter of configuration for me too.

Answer (score 1):

similar issue happened for me also. what I did:

1. backup current tslint.json(mv tslint.json tslint.json.bak)
2. regenerate tslint.json(npx tslint -i)
3. gradually put back your rules, etc.